# Different ways of partitioning a convex n -gon

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

What is the relationship between Catalan numbers and number of different ways of partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons?
Catalan numbers sequence describes number of different ways of triangulation of a polygon where the area of the polygon is partitioned into triangles but partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons is totally irrelevant to that triangulation. As an outcome of my research work I have derived a general formula for the partitioning of the set of vertices and there I used Catalan numbers sequence.

Comment: How is partitioning the set of vertices of a convex $n$-gon different from partitioning any other set of size $n$? I’m sure you have a reasonable question in mind, but you’re really not giving enough detail for most of us to understand what it is.

Comment: Really sorry for not including much important condition, here  you have to partition the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons not just polygons. I know there is a direct connection between triangulation of a convex n-gon and Catalan numbers but in this case the partitioning scenario is completely different and really complicated.( I have included that condition to the question)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Hipparchus_number

Comment: Mathstackexchange is a more welcoming forum for elementary questions.  Sorry!

Comment: @ Sam Nead I want to know how to connect partitioning of the area of a convex polygon and partitioning the set of vertices of a convex polygon. It's really hard to see that kind of relationship using the link you have suggested.

Comment: @ Jeremy Rickard ,  I could able to derive formula to cover all cases in partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons . I did it by observing the patterns of initial cases and to determine leading coefficient I used Catalan number sequence.

Comment: Is this the same as your question on people moving among vertices of a convex $n$-gon on nonintersecting paths, Janaka?

Comment: @GerryMyerson moving to another vertex without meeting another one along sides or diagonals is a combinatorics challenge created by myself . To solve the problem initial step required is to create nonintersecting closed loops because if you can do it thereafter you can easily obtain moving patterns by considering directed polygons. I have derived my formula using the relationship I found between Catalan numbers and partitioning the set of vertices of a convex polygon into nonintersecting polygons . Here my question is whether there is way to prove that connection.